# ajax login in yii framework

Tags: ajax, authentication, yii

I have new homepage with login and register with unlogin user.
homepage.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $("#btnLogin").click(function()
                {                    
                    var username= $("#usernamelogin").val();
                    var password=$("#passwordlogin").val();
                    var remember = $("#rememberlogin").is(':checked'); 
                    var dataString = 'usernamelogin='+ username + '&passwordlogin=' + password + '&rememberlogin=' + remember;
                    $.ajax
                    ({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "homepage",
                        data: dataString,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(html)
                        {
                            alert(html);
                        }

                    });
                });
            });


        </script>
<form action="" method="post" name="frmLogin" class="Login">
            <table width="960px" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="3" width="404"><label id="lbbanner"><b>UIT SOCIAL NETWORK</b></label></td>
                    <td width="216"><label>Username:</label></td>
                    <td width="324">Password:</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" witdth="200px" id ="usernamelogin" name="txtUsernameLogin" /></td>
                    <td><input type="password" width="200px" id="passwordlogin" name="txtPasswordLogin" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" id="rememberlogin" name="checkRemember" />&nbsp;Remember me!
                        <input type="button" value="Log in" id="btnLogin" name="Login"/></td>
                    <td colspan="2" align="right"></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>

                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

**In SiteController I have actionHomePage()**

```
 public function actionHomePage() {
        $model = new LoginForm();      
        $model->username = $_POST['usernamelogin'];
        $model->password = $_POST['passwordlogin'];
        $model->rememberMe = $_POST['rememberlogin'];
        //echo $model->errors;
        print_rcount(($model->getErrors()));
        //echo $model->username . "&&" . $model->password . "$$" .$model->rememberMe;
        // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid        
        if ($model->validate() && $model->login()) {
            $this->loginStatus = true;
            //$this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
            echo "SUCCESS";
        } else {

            echo "Error";
        }
    }
```

When I fill username and password with correct info but it return "ERROR"
$model->validate() is false but I have correct info.
I dont know what i am wrong in this part.

Comment: what is the error that you see? add a `var_dump($model->getErrors());` after `echo "Error";` to see the error in your alert box. So let me know the error that you see.

Comment: thank for your comment I found bug

Comment: ok, so what was it? i'm curious to know.

Comment: about remember login is set 0 or 1 but I send from my form is true or false. I try to show error but i dont know how? and thank you very much about how to show error.

Answer (score 1):

Your input variable names need to match the POST variables you are querying so

```
<td><input type="text" witdth="200px" id ="usernamelogin" name="txtUsernameLogin" /></td>
<td><input type="password" width="200px" id="passwordlogin" name="txtPasswordLogin" /></td>
```

should be like this:

```
<td><input type="text" witdth="200px" id ="usernamelogin" name="usernameLogin" /></td>
<td><input type="password" width="200px" id="passwordlogin" name="passwordLogin" /></td>
```

same for rememberlogin

Comment: but when I return echo $model->username . "&&" . $model->password . "$$" .$model->rememberMe; It return true what i have :-?

Comment: @chanhle Pls check ur login model and the rules() in it.

Answer (score -1):

because in actionHomePage() : $model->rememberMe = true or false; $_post return a string . You try :

```
($_POST['rememberlogin'] == "false") ? $model->rememberMe = false : $model->rememberMe = true ;
```